# Lazyweb: Is there something funny about how IE7 does onMouseOver Javascript on li elements with text?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom-events, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I'm an Ubuntu user, so I'm not knowledgeable of Internet Explorer. We have a Javascript based drop down menu thingie using li's and ul's and all that. It works fine in Firefox and IE6. However not in IE7. It looks like IE7 doesn't call the `onMouseOver` function unless you go over the text in the middle, as opposed to the blank area between the text and the edge of the li element (which is what IE6 does). Any hints on this?

UPDATE 21st May 2009 - I'm not sure what's going on here, but I've solved my problem another way.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a display:block to the element so it "spreads" out to width of the parent instead of just the width of textNode of the element.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you really should check out IES4Linux:
http://www.tatanka.com.br/ies4linux/page/Main_Page

It makes web development on Linux significantly easier (although it's not a "true" IE; for that you'd need a virtual machine, Windows install, and all the hassle that entails ... but IEs4Linux is a very good approximation).

Secondly, you should really read:
http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html

That page has a very nice explanation of IE layout issues, and how to get around them (display:block, as Jack suggested, is one approach, but it may create other issues for you, as that page explains).

Good luck.

Comment: Yeah I've heard of IEs4Linux. However at the moment I'm using a virtual machine, so it's more 'true' to IE. Also my reference to being an Ubuntu user is cause I hardly ever have to work with IE, so there might be something obvious I've missed.

Comment: Ah; then yeah, all you have missed is crazy IE rendering rules that make no sense and defy all standards ;-)  But that link I provided should help explain them.